# Code Coverage is to low on 'expecting to render' test in a specific Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

i am writing a simple test on a particular component of my application using `react-test-render`, and the test is expecting the component to render.

I have tried to implement the properties which are required to the component on the test file and still no results, the test coverage of component is still to low. the test is passing, i think the problem is on the functions.

```
   class Component extends React.PureComponent { 
        constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);

            this.function1 = this.function1.bind(this);
            this.function2 = this.function2.bind(this);
        }

        handleRef(element) {
            const { var1 } = this.props;

            this.iframe = element;
            if (var1) {
                var1(element);
            }
        }

        function2() {
            const {
                var2,
                var3,
                var4,
            } = this.props;

           if (!var2(this.iframe) && var3) {
           var3();
           localytics.tagEvent({ pageName: 'string' });
           return;
       }

       if (var3) {
            var3();
            performanceLog('The iframe has loaded at: ');
            localytics.tagEvent({ pageName: 'homepage:ok' });
       }
   }

       render() {

        //render html

     }
 }

AppFrame.propTypes = {
   //proptypes 
};

 AppFrame.defaultProps = {
      //default props
 };

 export default withStyles(styles)(AppFrame);
```

the test code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16.3';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import AppFrame from '../index';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('<AppFrame />', () => {
   it('Expect to render', () => {
     const renderedComponent = renderer.create(
        <AppFrame var1="test" var2={() => {}} />
     ).toJSON();

expect(renderedComponent).toMatchSnapshot();
});
});
```

test coverage screenshot:
[image: coverage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapshot testing covers only rendered items, it usually doesn't take into account other methods in class. You can call the [instance](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html#testrenderergetinstance) methods, and check if [stubbed](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#using-a-mock-function) props was called, i.e.:

Here is an example with [enzyme's shallow renderer](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md):

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('<AppFrame />', () => {
  const onErrorStub = jest.fn();

  it('Expect to render', () => {
    const renderedComponent = shallow(
       <AppFrame
          src="test"
          onLoad={() => {}}
          onError={onErrorStub}
          isLoadedSuccessfully={() => false} />
    );

    renderedComponent.instance().handleOnLoad();
    expect(onErrorStub).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

You might also want to test if stubs were called [with specific arguments](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-).

Also, check out `coverage` folder in your project - there should be a detailed report on what is (not) covered.

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: renderedComponent.getInstance(...).handleOnLoad is not a function` also the percentage is not changing unfortunately @Alex

Comment: @ArsenCenko, strange, It was ok when I checked. Maybe something related to `withStyles` hoc

Comment: did you check and coverage percentage goes 100% ? weird i think the %branch its becouse if conditions in the handleOnLoad function :/ @Alex

Comment: Coverage will be increased for sure, but to reach 100% you have to cover all such methods (i.e. `handleRef` too). I usually do it the way I described, and coverage becomes higher - that's I can say for sure. So, you can consider my answer as a general direction of coverage improve. :) @ArsenCenko

Comment: BTW, Can you check with `renderedComponent.root.handleOnLoad()` instead of `getInstance`? I usually prefer [shallow](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) of enzyme, instead of `testRenderer.create`, maybe something related. @ArsenCenko

Comment: the same error goes also with root, can you update the answer with the shallow of enzyme method please so i can check that :)

Comment: @ArsenCenko, it should work even with test-renderer, let's check one more thing: did you change your test to `const renderedComponent = renderer.create(<AppFrame.. />.);` (no `.toJSON()`) method, so `renderedComponent` contains result of `.create()` not of `.toJSON()` method?

Comment: its the same error even if i remove `.toJSON()` from the `renderedComponent` with `root` and also with `.getInstance()`

Comment: very strange, I just noticed that  `import AppFrame from '../index';` - can you confirm that it imports the correct component? Also, can you update question with `withStyles` hoc?

Comment: the import is correct, i have `withStyles` also in some others components and doesn't do the same thing on testing

Comment: @ArsenCenko, I updated answer with enzyme's shallow example

Comment: I think the issue is the `hoc` -  so `.getInstance()` returns `hoc` instance, not `AppFrame`. Can you try to export `AppFrame` with no hoc, and check? @ArsenCenko